# Change form behavior if query has parameter

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Now I am an MVC person, never really worked with WebForms, and had this been MVC I would know what to do. But I am working on an old software solution that was written in WebForms VB.NET.

[image: form]

So I have the above form where a user inputs a `username` and that then goes and retrieves data from database for that particular user and displays it on the page.

I want to add new behavior like pseudo code below:

```
If query string has a parameter username Then
    Grab username, submit form and do what you had to do
Else
    Behave exactly like before
End If
```

How can I achieve this WebForms .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

According to documentation, this can be a collection, so in most generic case you would need to check in a loop (and maybe grab the first value, discard the rest).

```
Dim userName As String
For Each item In Request.QueryString("UserName")
  userName = item
  Exit For
Next

If userName IsNot Nothing Then 'query string has a parameter username
```

[By default ASP.NET posts to itself](http://forums.asp.net/t/1048041.aspx?How%20to%20programmatically%20POST%20data%20to%20an%20aspx%20page%20), if you want a custom post, have a look into [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) collection.

Comment: Hmm .. I'm still not clear on the `posts to itself` bit. So say I have the `username` in the query string, do I need to do anything else? or would ASP.NET Webforms now assume the form was submitted and behave as I outlined originally? Thx

Comment: @Ciwan: If you don't do anything (no code behind), the form would post to itself, i.e. this is default behavior. So what you are trying to do instead? Which workflow would it trigger if you have a user name?